# How to Beat on the Brat?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm struggling with a few of the Beat on the Brat quests. I tried looking up some ways and perks to improve combat with fists, but I couldn't find much for 1v1 situations, mostly the perks deal with using your fists in regular game combat (utilizing cold blood stacks, 1 vs many enemies, etc).

The twins fight was relatively easy, and I'm sure it was supposed to be. However, fighting the army guy and the guy with the pregnant girlfriend was no easy task. It mostly involved me sprinting away from their hits, and going in for some heavy punches, just before running out of stamina so I could still move quickly.

These guys would still knock me out in about 3 or 4 hits, so I'd have to be extremely careful. Playing this way would take around 5+ minutes per fight, and if I made a mistake with them having 10% or less health, it would lead to a frustrating loss and a quick load. I'm not even going to get started on the Animals champion, since Rhino absolutely bodies me with this strategy.

IIRC using Gorilla Arms is not allowed for these fights, but I'm not confident on that. So, **how can I Beat on the Brat?**

Comment: I did these with a ranged/hacker build at first at it was pretty much impossible. Then at second playthrough with a melee build, they were hard but possible and I beat all opponents. In most fights you can find some manner of exploit and then just button mash from there. Melee in this game is pretty awful in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, Gorilla Arms *are* allowed. They make the fist fights much more manageable.

Additionally, while consumables are prohibited mid-fight they can be used before the fight for significant boosts.

Comment: I swear I remembered Rhino asking if i had Gorilla Arms on first fighting her, but maybe she said something about no mantis blades. Regardless, got em, and beat all the brats. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively easy way to win those fights, but it might require a few attempts:

All melee opponents seem to perform a certain number of moves until they run out of stamina. When they finish that series, there is a brief moment before they will start blocking, waiting for the stamina to come back. So the trick is to

1. Avoid the initial combo: move to the sides or back rather than block but stay close
2. When the opponent stops hitting, they might hang their head down for about a second - use it to hit them a few times, but not for too long
3. Rinse, repeat.

You can also cheat a little bit at the beginning of the fight, as there is a short time gap between the moment when your opponent turns hostile and when he lifts his arms. If you come very close to him after clicking "start fight", you can score a few sucker punches.